# Dynamic Where Condition on Entity Framework failed for Datetime with Cast

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I am using dynamic where clause with Entity Framework 4.0 to filter the results.

Like

```
ObjectQuery<T> tmp =  _context.MyTable.where("it.CreatedAt = @p0");
```

@p0 is a object parameter

This works perfectly fine.

But the problem is i want to something like:

```
where("CAST(it.CreatedAt as Date) = @p0");
```

And
    where("SqlServer.CAST(it.CreatedAt as Date) = @p0");

Both of them failed.

Any help is appreciated

UPDATE:

Error Info:

**Type 'Date' could not be found. Make sure that the required schemas are loaded and that the namespaces are imported correctly.**

And the where query is

```
 it.IsDeleted = true  and (  it.OrganizationName ='05 sep 2012' OR  Cast( it.CreatedAt as Date )  =@p4 OR  1=0 )
```

The Object Parameter is already supplied.

The value currently passing is '9/5/2012 12:00:00 AM'
and Like:

```
string temp = SearchedQuery.Trim();
 DateTime res;
 if (DateTime.TryParse(temp, out res))
{
 query += ((" Cast( it." + field.Name +  " as Date )  =@p" + i + ""));

 ObjectParameter pr = new ObjectParameter("p" + i, res);

 param.Add(pr);

 query += " OR ";
}
```

Comment: What is p0? If it's a datetime, then yes, this WHERE condition will fail. A date != a datetime.

Comment: @Arran ObjectParameter pr = new ObjectParameter("@p0" + i, DateTime.Now);   It is a object Parameter. And the error comes to be like Cast is not valid. Since cast is of sql server. I dont know how should i process in this case there are no eaxmples..

Comment: Yes, it's a datetime. A date will never be equal to any date time. You either need to CAST it as a DateTime, or make `@p0` just a date (`DateTime.Today`)

Comment: @Arran Please see my updated code. I think my question is not clear enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. This is not perfect but worked in some case in which i want. We can clean it more also

```
 string temp = SearchedQuery.Trim();
 DateTime res;
 if (DateTime.TryParse(temp, out res))
 {
 query += ((" ( it." + field.Name + " >@p" + i + ""));

 query += " AND ";

 ObjectParameter pr = new ObjectParameter("p" + i, res);

 i++;

 query += ((" it." + field.Name + " <@p" + i + " ) "));

 ObjectParameter pr1 = new ObjectParameter("p" + i, res.AddDays(1));

 param.Add(pr);
 param.Add(pr1);


 query += " OR ";
}
```